# Using Python to split a data text file into several text files for MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I have a data txt file formatted in a way to be loaded into a database (MySQL) in the following format (somewhat exaggerated):

data.txt

```
name   age profession datestamp
John   23  engineer   2020-03-01
Amy    17  doctor     2020-02-27
Gordon 19  artist     2020-02-27
Kevin  25  chef       2020-03-01
```

The above was generated by the following command executed through python:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/sample_data/data.txt' REPLACE INTO TABLE person_professions 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY 0x01 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 (name,age,profession,datestamp)
```

which creates data.txt; however, data.txt is really huge for this database to be inserted all at once (~200 MB insertion limit set), I want to slice the data up into several chunks (data_1.txt, data_2.txt, data_3.txt, etc.) and insert them one by one to avoiding hitting the insertion size limit. I know that you can go line by line and look for a condition to slice out the data for such as

```
with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    data = f.read().split('\n')
    if some condition:
       with open('data_1.txt', 'w') as f2:
            insert data
```

But I'm not too sure on how I could come up with a condition breakpoint to make it start inserting into a new txt file unless there's a better way of doing it.

Comment: Not a python answer, but since you are using a unix-ish system you probably have `split` available. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html

Comment: @AnthonyKong does that automatically split the file based on size and ensures no loss of data?

Comment: @SooWoo What's the original files size? What's your system's RAM? Can you please test the function I posted in the answer and let us know if it works because you can also read file line by line, it'll be much slower but it won't crash.

Comment: @ThaerA test function works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a function that could get the job done, depending on the size of the file. Explanation in code comments.

```
def split_file(file_name, lines_per_file=100000):
    # Open large file to be read in UTF-8
    with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as rf:
        # Read all lines in file
        lines = rf.readlines()
        print ( str(len(lines)) + ' LINES READ.')
        # Set variables to count file number and count of lines written
        file_no = 0
        wlines_count = 0
        # For x from 0 to length of lines read stepping by number of lines that will be written in each file
        for x in range(0, len(lines), lines_per_file):
            # Open new "split" file for writing in UTF-8
            with open( 'data' + '-' + str(file_no) + '.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as wf:
                # Write lines
                wf.writelines(lines[x:x+lines_per_file])
                # Update the written lines count
                wlines_count += (len(lines[x:x + lines_per_file]))
                # Update new "split" file count mainly for naming
                file_no+=1
        print(str(wlines_count) + " LINES WRITTEN IN " + str(file_no) + " FILES.")

# Split data.txt into files containing 100000 lines
split_file('data.txt',100000)
```